# Mysqli query doesn't work twice

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I cannot get my Mysqli queries to both work. If I comment out one function in my html, the other function is properly executed and vice versa.

```
function all_posts() {
    require_once 'database.inc.php';
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT variable_name, post_name, post_date, post_display FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");

    if (!$query)
        echo mysqli_error();

    while ($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $post_name = $results['post_name'];
        $post_date = $results['post_date'];
        $post_display = $results['post_display'];
        $variable_name = $results['variable_name'];

        echo "<a href='posts.php?post={$variable_name}'>";
        echo "<div class='entry'>";
        echo "<div class='entry_header'>";
        echo "<h2>{$post_name}</h2>";
        echo "<h3>{$post_date}</h3>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<p>{$post_display}</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</a>";
    }

    mysqli_free_result();
}

function all_sidebar_posts() {

    require_once 'database.inc.php';
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT variable_name, post_name FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");

    while ($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $post_name = $results['post_name'];
        $variable_name = $results['variable_name'];
        echo "<li><a href='posts.php?post=$variable_name'>$post_name</a></li>";
    }

    mysqli_free_result();
}
```

Here is the html that I am outputting to.

```
<ul>
    <?php all_sidebar_posts(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content_container">
    <?php all_posts(); ?>
</div>
```

I have tried using `mysqli_data_seek();` but haven't had luck. Perhaps I am not using it right? I have browsed many questions and found similar ones but I have tried them all to no avail. I am new to programming so I may be overlooking something basic. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: +1 for using `mysqli_`. Yes, that's how exciting it is!

Comment: how was you using `mysqli_data_seek()` ? because this should enable you to use the same query again for a different purpose

Comment: do not write code twice - `require_once 'database.inc.php';
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);`
 just write one the top and use `$mysqli` in functions like a global value.

Comment: Perhaps I was using it wrong. I had it set as    `mysqli_data_seek(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query), 0)` right after each while loop.

Comment: @AntonSementsov I kept getting confused with the scope of my variables and so I wrote some smelly code that at least works. Thanks though!

Comment: @AntonSementsov do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: @DarylGill how would you suggest it be used?

Comment: @Brannon I have posted this as a answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it wrong way.
**Never** mix your data manipulation code with presentation code.

First, get the posts into array:

```
require_once 'database.inc.php';
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

$sql = "SELECT variable_name, post_name, post_date, post_display 
        FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

and then use this `$data` array to display posts any times you need, simply using `foreach()`

Answer (score -1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Consult the manual for the usage of data_seek();

Take this example:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='1'";
$TheQuery -> $MySQLi->query($Query);
$Results = $TheQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$TheQuery->data_seek(0); // Lets you re-use the query

$Count = $TheQuery->num_rows; // Gets the count
```

so in your case:

You should perform the procedure method:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY Name";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        /* fetch row */
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        printf ("City: %s  Countrycode: %s\n", $row[0], $row[1]);


    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);

    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);


        /* free result set*/
        mysqli_free_result($result);

}
```

Comment: Am I incorrect in thinking that I should place `mysqli_data_seek(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query), 0)` at the end of each function's while loop?

Comment: according to an `if(!empty($query))` I put in the second query the query itself fails.

Comment: Careful, if you free the result it won't be available any longer, so it wouldn't be able to use `mysqli_data_seek`.

Comment: the $query is still being executed to discover whether it will return a set or empty result; try it in the context that I have put it, and update me on the results

Comment: @DiegoAgulló if I don't free the result wouldn't mysqli_fetch_assoc(); still be filled from the previous query?

Comment: @DarylGill im a little confused about the context. Sorry to be obnoxious and thanks for sticking with this question!